# Distro tags needs pruning, with special mention of the Ubuntu tag

Tags: discussion, tags

When hanging out in the Ask Ubuntu General Chatroom, [hbdgaf commented](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16663803#16663803):

> Wow... the Ubuntu tag blew up on UL today >.>

This piqued my curiosity and I went to <s>witch hunt</s> investigate his statement. Unsurprisingly I found clear examples of people tagging questions with Ubuntu as the only tag (which is IMO, not helpful, *at all*) when they were not even Ubuntu-related questions:

- [Difference between sdX and vdX](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145332/deffernt-between-sda-and-vda)

or where OP only happened to be using Ubuntu:

- [How to provision software across multiple laptops](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/145212/41104)
- [Solution to integer expression expected](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/145223/41104)
- [How to provision software across multiple laptops](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/145212/41104)

and on most of them, the tag didn't help to get the questions answered (none of the active members of Ask Ubuntu happened to answer those questions). So, since distributions tags can be helpful, I see that they are in most cases abused, or are just not relevant.

So, I ask you to do the following:

1. If you see a distribution tag where it's not relevant, please remove
   it
2. Check out combinations of tags where the distribution is not relevant (off 
   the top of my head, text-processing questions are answered with POSIX compatible answers)
3. Search for questions that features only one of these tags.

I think this can be done at the same time that we answer questions, and will also give questions that fell through the cracks due being mis-tagged another opportunity to get answers.

Answer (score 4):

[I've made a query to help with the third point.](http://data.stackexchange.com/unix/query/219777/find-lonely-tags)

It only search for questions only tagged with any: debian, ubuntu, centos, kali-linux, linux-mint, fedora, arch-linux and rhel.