# "Merge [distro-version] tags into [distro] tags", should we?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Following up [previous discussion](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3102/41104) we definitively found those tags useless, so there are two options to make the change definitive:

- Manual cleanup (bleh! but yay!)
- Automated (yay! but bleh!)

Why those reactions, well, manual cleanup also allows us to review the state of other tags, add tag, fix title, etc. make more improvements. The problem is that as "manual" implies, we need to use "user time" to do this. The automated way is the opposite, it doesn't use user time (only moderators [>:)](http://xkcd.com/541/)), but leaves potential fixes that can be applied to such posts that a manual clean up could address.

What $PATH should we take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have merged [wheezy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wheezy) into [debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debian), the various fedoras into [fedora](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fedora), [centos6](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/centos6) and [centos7](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/centos7) into [centos](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/centos) and [sles11](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sles11) into [sles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sles).

I can't find any other version-specific tags so I think that's the lot of them. If anyone finds new ones, please leave me a comment here, or flag the relevant post for mod attention and point out the tag.

Comment: We've now become infected with several  [tag:fedoraNNN], a few [tag:gnome-X.Y] ([tag:gnome3] makes sense, but not minor versions), and [tag:jessie].

Answer (score 6):

Posts with /distro-version tags aren't significantly more in need of editing than average. There are plenty of /distro tags that shouldn't have that tag, too. Having decided that having the version in the tag is useless, changing /distro-version to /distro does not remove any information. So there is no advantage to a manual cleanup. There are obvious downsides to a manual cleanup: it takes significant effort and bumps questions.

Hence: **merge**.

Note that I'm specifically talking about /distro-version tags like [fedora20](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fedora20) or [wheezy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wheezy). /distro-variant tags like [kubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kubuntu) are a different matter; if we decide to get rid of them (and I'm not saying it's a good idea to do that), we'd have to decide whether to change [kubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kubuntu) into [ubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu), [kde](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kde) or both, on each question separately.

Answer (score 2):

Unofficial list of distro-version tags, feel free to add more:

- Debian: [wheezy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wheezy) [jessie](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jessie) [stretch](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stretch)
- Fedora: [fedora18](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fedora18) [fedora19](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fedora19) [fedora-16](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fedora-16) [fedora20](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fedora20)
- CentOS: [centos6](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/centos6) [centos7](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/centos7)
- SLES: [sles11](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sles11)
- etc.?