# This criquet needs help!

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

After we decided [we don't need version specific tags](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3102/41104), nothing had changed:

- [debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debian) got an average of 1 question/day in the last 30 days
- In the last 24 hours, it got 6 questions.
- [jessie](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jessie) has an worse unanswered rate than [debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debian): 57% vs 52% for the last 30 days, 87% vs 70% in the last 7.

In summary, questioner asking questions with the tag jessie tend to be worse off than those that use just debian as tag. Can we bury it under 6 feet again?

Apparently was silently created 10 months ago by some user. stretch, [fedora25](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fedora25) and [fedora24](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fedora24) should have the same fate. [fedora23](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fedora23) and [rhel7](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rhel7) were late to the party.

Comment: There are also a bunch of [tag:fedora25] [tag:fedora24] etc.

Comment: @mattdm slow grind for those

Comment: Question from ignorance: why a slow grind? [terdon merged them previously](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/a/3144/117549); I assume it was an O(1) operation on his part...?

Comment: @JeffSchaller we, as community, can handle it. We don't need mom and dad every time we need to clean something up.

Comment: I don't doubt we can do it -- I've made several smaller-scale efforts to clean up some tags; I just wondered if there was an easier, more-direct way to do it. If manually re-tagging is "it", I'm happy to help.

Comment: Manually re-tagging is "it" — at least for 10k+ users inline tag editing makes it less painful (especially with the Fedora tags; just backspace over the last two characters, then hit space and enter).

Comment: fedora24 and fedora25 are emptied out as of this moment

Comment: [tag:fedora23] has been cleared out

Comment: [tag:rhel7] has been cleared out

Comment: Is the next step to have a moderator merge the tags?

Comment: I'm disturbed by the assumption that questions are unanswered because of their low quality.

Comment: @JeffSchaller no, the tags are no more. As long as they aren't recreated (if you have 10k check the new tags tool) we are done.

Comment: @TomášZato I didn't address the quality of the questions...

Comment: Could they be recreated, though? Just trying to keep things clean.

Comment: @JeffSchaller as long as someone has the privilege, but there's a warning.

Answer (score 11):

I've cleaned up the [jessie](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jessie) and [stretch](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stretch) tags. As I understand it, if the tags don't get any new content they should be automatically deleted.

Comment: And they're gone!

Comment: fedora25 is clear; soon, fedora24!

Comment: [tag:fedora24] is clear! W00t!